# .Net Core Firebase Google Email Authentication With JWT - 401

Tags: c#, firebase, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt

I'm trying to use `firebase` email authentication on my `.net core` web-backend via `JWT`. I couldn't find detailed and clear example.

1. I get successful login on my `android` app then i get the `IdToken`.
2. I'm sending `IdToken` with prefix `"Bearer"` on PostMan(or app) to my Controller. But it gives `401`

Whatever i tried i couldn't get the `200`. Only `401`.

**My service Configuration:**

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(o =>
    {
        o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://securetoken.google.com/myapp-c1e32";
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/myapp-c1e32",
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = "myapp-c1e32",
            ValidateLifetime = true
        };
    });
```

**My Controller:**

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public ActionResult GetAllRoomsWithOtherInfos(int id)
{
    var rooms = _roomService.GetAllRoomsWithOtherInfos(id);
    return Ok(rooms);
}
```

**My Request:**

```
http://localhost:5000/Room/GetAllRoomsWithOtherInfos/1
```

**Exception Message On Log:**

> Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10501: Signature
>   validation failed. Unable to match keys:

**Also my app and service configurations**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddDbContext<TaraftarServerContext>(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString(GlobalVariables.DbConnectionName)));
        services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add<GlobalExceptionFilter>();
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver())
            .AddFluentValidation();
        services.AddKendo();
        services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
            {
                hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            })
            .AddJsonProtocol(jsonOptions =>
            {
                jsonOptions.PayloadSerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
                jsonOptions.PayloadSerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            });
        services.AddWebClientServices();

        // configure strongly typed settings objects
        var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

        // this method is above configuration where the jwt is ( My service Configuration:)
        services.AddFirebaseAuthentication(Configuration);

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("tr")
        };

        app.UseRequestLocalization(
            new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("tr"),
                SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures,
                FallBackToParentCultures = true,
                FallBackToParentUICultures = true,
                RequestCultureProviders = null
            });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Room}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

    }
```

> **.Net Core Version : 2.2**

Comment: Do you really mean the `IdToken`? Shouldn't it be the `AccessToken`?

Comment: @KirkLarkin return paremeter name is `IdToken` it should be the same with `AccessToken`. In the end it is token. also no other value returns that you can say it is token.

Comment: which version of .net core are you using. Also make sure your app.UseMvc() is at the end in your configuration method.

Comment: @maxspan i edited my answer. please check it.
.net core version is : 2.2

Comment: it seems to generated token is not valid or the encoding of the token is not correct.

Comment: Is your android app and the api are registered correctly with fire base. it seems the generated token is not valid for the api. Try this sample code.                                https://github.com/markvincze/AspNetCoreFirebaseAuthSample

Comment: @maxspan token generated by google and there is no parameters to take it from google in diffrent algorithm ( as i searched ). Also when i try to encode my token. It looks okay.

Comment: have you tried the code sample

Comment: not yet. if it helps. i will return. thanks in advance.